# Find the identity element of a set with respect to a given operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

The following is an example from Carol Whitehead's A Guide to Abstract Algebra (1988).

[image]

I apologize if I am missing something but it is not true that $1+2a\neq 0$, $\forall a\in \mathbb{Q}$ ($\mathbb{Q}$ denoting obviously rational numbers). If there was $\mathbb{Q}^+$ instead, there would be any problem with the solution.

Is there a typo? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think their quantifiers are written unclearly.  What they should mean is that it is not true that, for all $a\in \mathbb Q$ we have $1+2a=0$.  All you need here is to take a single $a\in\mathbb Q$ for which $1+2a\neq 0$, take $a=1$ for example.  Thus no non-zero element has a chance of being the identity.

Comment: Should say:  I'd prefer to simply note that $0$ clearly works as a two-sided identity at that the usual argument proves there can't be two identities (what would $e\circ 0$ be?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not wrong the solution is not correct, however, note that since $1+2a\neq0$ for positive $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, the only possible identity is $e=0$ since $a\circ e=a$ must hold **for all** $ a.$

Answer (score 1):

The book should have

> since $1+2a\ne0$ for at least one $a\in\mathbb{Q}$

There is a much better way to go. Suppose $e$ is the identity element. Then, in particular, $e\circ0=0$, which means
$$
e+0+2e\cdot0=0
$$
and therefore $e=0$. Note that this does *not* show that $0$ is the identity element, but just that *if* there is one, it must be $0$.

Now we check that, for every $a\in\mathbb{Q}$,
$$
0\circ a=0+a+2\cdot0\cdot a=a
$$
and we're done.

Actually we should generally also check that $a\circ0=a$, but this particular operation is clearly commutative, so the further check is not needed.